# Export a list of invalid geometries using Python

Tags: python, gdal, geometry, ogr, invalid-data

Is there a way to export a list of layers containing invalid geometry (e.g. self-intersections) via Python?

Our GIS server contains over 40,000 layers, some of which have all sorts of errors that simply cannot be identified manually.

Is there some sort of OGR/GDAL command that can perform this?

Comment: For layers that are in a dataset where gdal can do sql-queries you might be able to query a condition `-sql "select * from filename WHERE not ST_IsValid(geometry)"`. Otherwise mass converting to sqlite or postgis and using the abilities of these formats might work.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify the data format in question.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#polygons) library. You can loop ever the features and check the is_valid propery. This is from the docs:

> object.is_valid
>   Returns True if a feature is “valid” in the sense of [1](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#polygons).
>
> A valid LinearRing may not cross itself or touch itself at a single point. A valid Polygon may not possess any overlapping exterior or interior rings. A valid MultiPolygon may not collect any overlapping polygons. Operations on invalid features may fail.