# Python OGR SQL - Finding invalid geometry

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I previously asked this question@ [regarding finding files that contain an invalid geometry using OGR.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226091/export-a-list-of-invalid-geometries-using-python)

The following SQL command was suggested to me, which seemed to work a treat: `-sql "select * from filename WHERE not ST_IsValid(geometry)"`

I am now trying to get this to work under python using the following code:

```
from osgeo import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('MapInfo File') 
dataSource = driver.Open(file, 0)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer() 

result = dataSource.ExecuteSQL("select * from file WHERE ST_IsValid(geometry)")
featureCount = result.GetFeatureCount() 

print (featureCount)
```

Upon running the code however, I get the following error message: `ERROR 1: Undefined function 'ST_IsValid' used.`

Does anyone know how I go about checking `ST_IsValid` under python?

Comment: ST_IsValid is a SQLite/Spatialite function. I believe that by adding dialect SQLite it will work http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.DataSource-class.html#ExecuteSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the plain vanilla OGR SQL includes spatial functions? You can specify pszDialect in the parameters for ExecuteSQL, for example to use SQLITE's spatial functions. http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html

Comment: Excellent, using 'dataSource.ExecuteSQL("select * from HousingOptions WHERE ST_IsValid(geometry)", dialect = "SQLITE")' seems to have done the trick. I am getting some kind of logical output now.

Thank you!